# Can't draw with CreateGraphics

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

I just have a Panel and want to draw on it. Without the use of its Paint event. So i tried this and it doesn't work.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 10, 10);
}
```

If someone could provide me with explonation and example code that would be nice.

Comment: Add a button to your form and draw in click event handler.

Comment: Your form is not visible while it fires Load event. That's why you didn't see the result.

Comment: This doesn't make much sens as it will be wiped after panel redrawn - you should draw in `WM_PAINT` of the control

Comment: Can you explain why would you draw on a Control's Device Context *without the use of its Paint event*? -- There are occasions when you may need to do something like this, but it's a quite specific use case. If you describe what's yours, someone may suggest something that actually works.

Comment: @Jimi I meant without creating the paint event in design, im dynamicly creating them in a method and needed to paint on them, i could have said that before tho, im sorry for my mistake

Comment: Then you accepted the wrong answer (which s wrong in any case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `CreateGraphics` to paint something in a `synchronous` way. For example, to paint in a Bitmap and save it to disk. May be a better way if you add an event handler to `Paint` event of your panel, in the designer or in form constructor:

```
panel1.Paint += this.OnPanel1_Paint;
```

And paint in that event:

```
private void OnPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 10, 10);
}
```

You don't need dispose this graphics here, only paint that you want.

In this way, when you need force the repaint (for example, you add another rectangle on every click in the panel) you must invoke `panel1.Invalidate();`. This method tell to Windows that you need repaint the control and Windows invoke the event as soon as possible. Obviously, you need to know what to draw and it's depends of your application. You can have a `List` of rectangles and add a new rectangle on each click. Then, in `OnPanel1_Paint` method, you draw all your list rectangles.